# windows 7 network access. some can some cannot

Tags: windows-7, networking

The main problem is why only 2 PCs can't access the network, yet others can.

- COM16 can freely access any pc.
- COM16 is sharing drive D, drive F, and 1 folder.
- COM11 able to access COM16 only folders, not the drives.
- COM17 and ADMIN-PC totally not able to access com16
- IP access also failed.
- All PCs belong to the workgroup WORKGROUP. No known IP conflicts exist.

All settings shown are from COM17 and are exactly the same as COM16

Network:

[image: Network Settings]

Permissions:

[image: Permissions]

Ping:

[image: Ping]

Sharing Settings:

[image: Sharing settings]

LAN Network Settings:

[image: LAN Network Settings]

Security Settings:

[image: Security Settings]

Disk Sharing Settings:

[image: Disk Sharing Settings]

Using Ip in Explorer:

[image: Using Ip in Explorer]

Comment: Use the IPs instead of names.

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: That means some configuration is preventing access. It could be a security setting of the anti-virus that overwrites firewall policies, for example.

Comment: full removal internet security, restore windows firewall default not even help.

Comment: How are your IPs controlled ? Do you have a firewall/router in the network ?

Comment: every pc with own ips using switch. firewall only using AV/windows. stock router usage as internet only.

Comment: What gives the IP addreses ?

Comment: Finally i solved it.
Reset Windows Security settings to default values.

Open cmd ( Run as admin )
Key in as below:
secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose
restart pc. and works like charm.. answer from google like no tomorrow.

Thanks Overmind for your efforts to help..

Comment: I'll put things into an answer so it will be useful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the correct services are working, in situations like this one it means some configuration is preventing access. 
That could be:

- network firewall with specific rules configured
- anti-virus
- anti-virus controlling security settings/firewall
- the actual windows firewall
- GPO or general security settings

For each situation, the proper things must be checked: the firewall rules (both for network and for windows), the anti-virus security settings. For AV and firewall the settings can be reset from their configuration and the general security settings can be reset using the `secedit` command.

Also, note that simply selecting 'public' instead of 'work' or 'home' when connecting a computer to the network will prevent it from being correctly accessible, in which case this can be chanced in several manners, including using powershell's `Set-NetConnectionProfile` command and `-NetworkCategory` parameter. This could fix the problem without the need of a full security settings reset.